# datetime logic between different times

Tags: php

I've been working on a project for more than 14 hours straight and I got stuck on something that seems so simple, yet I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Part of the project description:

```
- if the flight has an ACT, remarks should say either Arrived or Departed
- if the flight has only has SCT, repeat SCT on to Estimated column and remarks should be On Time
- if the flight has SCT and EST but no ACT, compare SCT and EST:
    --> if EST is more than SCH by 5 minutes or more, remarks = Late
    --> if EST is less than SCH by 5 minutes or more, remarks = Early
    --> everything else (on time or with a time frame of 10 minutes), remarks = On Time
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function remarks_info($sct, $est, $act) {

    $remarks = '';

    if(!empty($act)) {
        $remarks = 'Departed'; // this part needs to be dynamic, but let's use Departed for now
    } elseif(empty($est) && empty($act)) {
        if(!empty($sct)) {
            $est = $sct;
            $remarks = 'On Time';
        }
    } elseif (!empty($sct) && !empty($est) && empty($act)) {

        if(strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) > 300) {
            $remakes = 'Delayed to ' . $est;
        } elseif (strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) < 300) {
            $remarks = 'Earlier at ' . $est;
        } else {
            $remarks = 'On Time';
        }

    }

    return $remarks;

}
```

Info:

(sct, est, act) are dates taken from a database

```
example: 2015-03-24 20:13:00
SCT   - datetime
EST   - datetime
ACT   - datetime
```

The issue:

Some results don’t return the desired remarks information (based on the project requirements, and the code logic I wrote).

For example, one of the database entries has a SCT value of =“2015-03-24 19:35:00”, a EST value of = “2015-03-24 19:35:00” and a empty value on ACT.  This one is returning “Earlier at 2015-03-24 19:35:00”

Another example, an entry with a SCT value of = “2015-03-24 16:15:00”, a EST value of = “2015-03-24 16:20:00” and a empty value on ACT. This example returns “On Time”

I would appreciate it so much if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with it? Provide an example in which it gives the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, one of the database entries has a SCT value of =“2015-03-24 19:35:00”, a EST value of = “2015-03-24 19:35:00” and a empty value on ACT. This one is returning “Earlier at 2015-03-24 19:35:00”

This is because EST == CST and as such it will be caught by the following condition:

```
} elseif (strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) < 300) {
    $remarks = 'Earlier at ' . $est;
}
```

The correct condition would be:

```
} elseif (strtotime($sct) - strtotime($est) >= 300) {
    $remarks = 'Earlier at ' . $est;
}
```

As in, scheduled time is at least 5 minutes later than estimated time.

> Another example, an entry with a SCT value of = “2015-03-24 16:15:00”, a EST value of = “2015-03-24 16:20:00” and a empty value on ACT. This example returns “On Time”

Your first condition doesn't test the range inclusively, i.e. you should test for 'at least' instead of 'more than'.

```
if(strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) >= 300) {
    $remarks = 'Delayed to ' . $est;
}
```

As in, estimated time is at least 5 minutes later than scheduled time.

Comment: This fixed the first example, and now it returns "On Time", since both values (sct, and est) are the same. However, the second example is returning an empty remark. Notice that on the second example, it has a sct value of 2015-03-24 16:15:00 and est of 2015-03-24 16:20:00 (5 minutes difference).

Comment: @Adrian.S Doh, there was a typo ... but the logic was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'EST' is estimated and 'SCH'/'SCT' is scheduled, the following logic is not correct:

```
if(strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) > 300) {
    $remakes = 'Delayed to ' . $est;
} elseif (strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) < 300) {
    $remarks = 'Earlier at ' . $est;
} else {
    $remarks = 'On Time';
}
```

It probably should be:

```
// Estimated - Scheduled is 5 mins or more
if(strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) >= 300) {
    $remarks = 'Delayed to ' . $est; // typo!
// Estimated - Scheduled is -5 mins or less (note the change)
} elseif (strtotime($est) - strtotime($sct) <= -300) {
    $remarks = 'Earlier at ' . $est;
} else {
    $remarks = 'On Time';
}
```

Comment: I copy+pasted your code, and it has the same issue as Jack's answer. The second example keeps returning an empty remark, when it should show "Delayed to" since there is 5 minutes in between (late).

Comment: We both missed the typo: `remakes` should be `remarks`.